# Configure Web Deploy Publishing - Unable to grant user

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have an IIS7 Web Site configured with a physical path pointing to a UNC Share. This works fine. However, when trying to configure Web Deploy for this site (Right Click on site -> Deploy -> Configure Web Deploy Publishing) I get:

*One or more errors occurred:
Unable to grant user 'MYDOMAIN\MyUser' full control on 'MyWeb'.*

The user account in question has full control on the UNC share.

If I change the Web Site path to a local server address, I can configure Web Deploy successfully.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had moved the wwwroot directory without updating the Website's Basic Settings, and the IIS Manager could not access the web.config.